# Interactive matplotlib code worked on jupyter but stuck on PyQt5

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas, pyqt5, draggable

I managed to create movable lines on a jupyter notebook by copying the code and editing it so that it worked the way I wanted. I also have this code as an example to get this plot works on PyQt5 but it won't work and I cant drag the line, does anyone have a solution?

zone.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as lines
import lasio
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar


class draggable_lines:
    def __init__(self, ax, kind, XorY):
        self.ax = ax
        self.c = ax.get_figure().canvas
        self.o = kind
        self.XorY = XorY

        if kind == "h":
            x = [-1, 1]
            y = [XorY, XorY]

        elif kind == "v":
            x = [XorY, XorY]
            y = [-1, 1]
            
        self.line = lines.Line2D(x, y, picker=5)
        self.ax.add_line(self.line)
        self.c.draw_idle()
        self.sid = self.c.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.clickonline)

    def clickonline(self, event):
        if event.artist == self.line:
            print("line selected ", event.artist)
            self.follower = self.c.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.followmouse)
            self.releaser = self.c.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.releaseonclick)

    def followmouse(self, event):
        if self.o == "h":
            self.line.set_ydata([event.ydata, event.ydata])
        else:
            self.line.set_xdata([event.xdata, event.xdata])
        self.c.draw_idle()

    def releaseonclick(self, event):
        if self.o == "h":
            self.XorY = self.line.get_ydata()[0]
            self.this = self.XorY
        else:
            self.XorY = self.line.get_xdata()[0]
        global tes
        tes = self.XorY

        self.c.mpl_disconnect(self.releaser)
        self.c.mpl_disconnect(self.follower)
```

That zone.py is worked on jupyter but when I tried it in PyQt5, only a horizontal line plot that cant moving. The file below is PyQt5 main file

tes.py

```
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from zone import draggable_lines


class MyGraph(FigureCanvas):


    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):

        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.axes.grid(True)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

        # To store the 2 draggable points
        self.list_points = []


        self.show()
        draggable_lines(self.axes, "h", 0.5)
        self.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyGraph()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: There's no persistent reference to `draggable_lines`, so at least make it so: `self.lines = draggable_lines(self.axes, "h", 0.5)` (also, use capitalized names for classes). Also, change those `setSizePolicy` and `updateGeometry` calls to proper ones: `self.setSizePolicy(...)` and `self.updateGeometry()` (which, by the way, is pointless at that point in the code). Also, don't use globals.